# gRPC not dropping disconnected channel

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Start server
2. Send a client RPC to server
3. Restart server
4. Using the same client, send another RPC. The call will fail
5. Send another RPC, this call will success

Also I found that if the server is leave stopped for a long time before starting up again, the call in step 5 will return "channel is in state TRANSIENT_FAILURE" as well.

Example code: https://github.com/whs/grpc-repro
(Install from requirements.txt then run main.py)

**Expected result**

All call should success.

Tested with Python grpcio==1.19.0 server/client and with go-grpc server. I tried setting grpc.max_connection_age_grace_ms, grpc.max_connection_age_ms, grpc.max_connection_idle_ms, grpc.keepalive_time_ms, grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls but they doesn't seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is duplicated with https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/grpc-io/199V_iF0NMw/NahHz_vMBwAJ.

---

The feature you want probably is "[wait_for_ready](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.UnaryUnaryMultiCallable)". In case of TRANSIENT_FAILURE (server not available temporarily), it will automatically wait for the channel become READY again without failing. [Read more](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgrpc%2Fproposal%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2FL42-python-metadata-flags.md&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNF9qWH251rghzyygYcF530BfBoYRA) about wait for ready.